# How can I dynamically load modules that rely on modules in my main bundle?

Tags: dynamic-loading, esbuild

I want to have my main application deployed in a bundle, but allow other developers to author extension modules, which will be dynamically loaded on demand.
Code is written in TypeScript and I am using esbuild for both, outputting in iife.

If I try to dynamically import another module I see the error

`Dynamic require of '...' is not supported`

which comes from `__require()`, defined in the bundle prolog.

I suppose the root problem here is that the knowledge about the modules that constitute the bundle is not available at runtime.  Is it possible to dynamically load an external module in this way, where it has dependencies on modules in the main bundle?